# Java comparator sort in reverse order

Tags: java, sorting, compare, comparator

I would like to sort from highest to lowest.

From lowest to highest, you would normally do:

```
@Override
    public int compare(Person p1, Person p2) {
        return (p1.getAge() - p2.getAge());
}
```

This would sort people by age from lowest to highest.

How do I do the reverse of this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write another `Comparator` like this

```
@Override
public int compare(Person p1, Person p2) {
   return (p2.getAge() - p1.getAge());
}
```

If the return value is negative, then the first object param is smaller than the second one.

If return value is zero then both are equally comparable (does not mean equal, but equal objects must return zero)

Take a look at [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#compare(T,%20T)) for more information

Comment: Really? It's that simple? Maybe it's because I don't know what is being returned. What does that returned value signify?